# When i tried to run a small script it shows" No handlers could be found for logger "scenario guide""

Tags: flask, flask-ask

When I tried to execute the given code, I get No handlers could be found for logger "scenario guide". I dont know what handler to use can anyone help me on it?

```
import inspect
import os
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question,request
from afg import Supervisor

app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app, "/")
sup = Supervisor('scenario.yaml')

class check:
    @ask.launch
    @sup.guide
    def launched():
      return question(render_template('welcome'))

    @ask.intent('firstIntent')
    @sup.guide
    def choose_first():
      return question(render_template('first'))

    @ask.intent('secondIntent')
    @sup.guide
    def choose_second():
      return question(render_template('second'))

    @ask.intent('thirdIntent')
    @sup.guide
    def choose_third():
      return statement(render_template('third'))

    @ask.intent('byeIntent')
    @sup.guide
    def choose_bye():
      pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By removing `class check:` from your code, you will be able to run the script.

```
import inspect
import os
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question,request
from afg import Supervisor

app = Flask(__name__)
ask = Ask(app, "/")
sup = Supervisor('scenario.yaml')

@ask.launch
@sup.guide
def launched():
    return question(render_template('welcome'))

@ask.intent('firstIntent')
@sup.guide
def choose_first():
    return question(render_template('first'))

@ask.intent('secondIntent')
@sup.guide
def choose_second():
    return question(render_template('second'))

@ask.intent('thirdIntent')
@sup.guide
def choose_third():
    return statement(render_template('third'))

@ask.intent('byeIntent')
@sup.guide
def choose_bye():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Also if you are looking to create class based views in your flask server, please refer [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/). 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: i tried it without class  the result is same no handlers could be found for logger "scenario guide"

Comment: Are you sure you are providing a scenario.yaml file ? Maybe you are missing that.

Comment: i do support the program with scenario.yaml @george-j-padayatti